# recommendation of a Non-relational database with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, non-relational-database

I want to start playing with non-relational database, but want something that is popularly used with Rails. I'm considering the ones in the article and leaning towards Voldemort or CouchDB:

http://www.ithighlight.com/2009/07/list-of-companies-powered-by-non-relational-database/

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home)

See the [getting started](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+-+Getting+Started) section for Rails

**Edit**

As pointed out by Dan, there was actually a [Railscast episode about MongoDB](http://railscasts.com/episodes/194-mongodb-and-mongomapper) today. The video there demonstrates how to use MongoDB with Rails. Thanks for sharing, Dan.

Comment: +1 to MongoDB, There's also a new Railscast about it today: http://railscasts.com/episodes/194-mongodb-and-mongomapper

Comment: Thanks. Also, I've heard CouchDB is quite slow compared to MongoDB and Voldemort